# google cloud platform pricing - delete account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just sign in to google cloud platform, and I got a message that I earn 300$ free trial. Can anyone please answer me if I got charge for anything. 
I did it by mistake and I can't able to delete it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a First time Signup Bonus google will give you 1 Year of Free Subscription. for signup you should link your Credit card. (i think you too linked it. thats why you fear about it.)  as per google said, you have been given 300$ worth paid service for the period of 1 year. till that you will not charged until this,

> For example, only the portion of your Google App Engine usage above
>   the App Engine free daily usage limits is charged against your $300
>   credit. In addition, if your App Engine usage is below the free daily
>   usage limits, your app will continue to run even after the free trial
>   ends.

also you can use that credit in paid google API's

> You can use the $300 credits to call any paid Google APIs or for any
>   Google Cloud Platform services.

**Charging:** Google will charge only after your subscription was expired or if you reached your 300$ benefits. Google won't charge without your permission. so, your card was secured. dont fear about it.

**About cancellation:**

> If you want to leave the free trial, there's nothing to do. Your trial
>   automatically expires after 12 months, and you will not be charged
>   during the free trial period unless you upgrade to a paid account.

**Please Note**
Your credit card is not charged unless you upgrade to a paid account.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.